# Docker - Mac OSX Ubuntu fails on apt-get update

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I'm using Ubuntu Docker image: `ubuntu:14.04`

I want to update my tree using:

```
RUN apt-get  update
```

But i'm keep getting this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried several method including `apt-get clean` and `RUN rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`

None of them solves the problem.

Any idea how can I ignore this error and keep building the container?

**UPDATE:**

That's my full Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

VOLUME ["/var/www"]

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes redis-tools git nano curl sendmail openssh-server apache2 supervisor php5 php5-curl php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-gd php5-json php5-ldap php5-mysql php5-pgsql php5-mcrypt php5-xdebug
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

RUN useradd ubuntu -d /home/ubuntu
RUN usermod -a -G sudo ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh
RUN chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh

ADD apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN php5enmod mcrypt
RUN sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
RUN sed -ri 's/^PermitRootLogin.*$/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#Add XDEBUG
RUN echo "[xdebug]" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.show_local_vars=0" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.show_exception_trace=0" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

#Allow SSH Root
ADD sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN service ssh reload
RUN service ssh restart

#Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ADD run /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run
EXPOSE 22 80
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

Comment: Could you post your whole Dockerfile? It works for me: `FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update`

Comment: Have you checked if your `ubuntu:14.04` image is up to date? Try doing `docker pull ubuntu:14.04` to be sure

Comment: @WaleryStrauch I added it to my question

Comment: @thaJeztah the pull actually helped. But for some reason, it still had the same error in the package, but it just skipped it.. Maybe it something with caching ?

Comment: You can always use `docker build --no-cache` to skip caching, not sure what's causing this; something with a mirror not being up to date?

Comment: Maybe so.. I used no caching that why it was weird

Comment: @thaJeztah post it is an answer please so i could expect it

Comment: @AsafNevo done; see below

Comment: The GPG errors happen for me even with a no-cache build, I'm not behind a corporate proxy, and it works for others on my team. The "Screen Time" fix didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible you have an outdated version of Ubuntu in your image cache. Run `docker pull ubuntu:14.04` to make sure you have the latest version present.

`apt-get update` should work out of the box; if it's not working, something else is wrong (possibly a caching mirror that's out of date, or a proxy server causing issues).

Also, to skip docker's caching mechanism during a build, you can use the `--no-cache` option; `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: This thing is still happening to me.. I just redownloaded ubuntu14.04 and yet I keep receiving `W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: are you behind a (corporate) proxy?

Comment: Nope.. my personal mac

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was due to Screen Time on my mac. (why tf is this autoenabled on MacOS install??).  Anyway, head to setting, find Screen Time, and then disable the damn thing. Hopefully this help many hours lost for some poor Mac user.

Comment: and another thing. WHY does screen time even prevent docker files from being downloaded????? my goodness!

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. Also the idea that screentime can mess up ubuntu docker images is beyond belief.

Comment: thats what i was thinking, until i disabled it.  This answer has also 2 upvotes, so it looks like it has helped 2 other people besides me

Answer (score 1):

I recently bumped into the same issue and I solved it disabling iCloud Private Relay.

It seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6030)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before `RUN apt-get update` in your dockerfile:

```
RUN gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv 16126D3A3E5C1192
RUN gpg --export --armor 16126D3A3E5C1192 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: This should not be needed; `apt-get update` should work out of the box, if not, something's wrong